# Public void exporttoexcel(datagridview gridviewid, string excelfilename) {

Tags: c#, asp.net, using

I am trying to export the data from the ACCDB file to Excel.

and its working but when I am export in excel file is empty there is no data.

---

### Below is code

What I have tried:

```
{

    private void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ExportToExcel(dataGridView1,"ExportedUserDetail");

    }
    public void ExportToExcel(DataGridView gridviewID, string excelFilename)
    {


        DateTime from = dateTimePicker1.Value;
        string date1 = from.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
        string fromdate = date1 + " " + "12:00:00" + " " + "AM";

        DateTime to = dateTimePicker2.Value;
        string date2 = to.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
        string todate = date2 + " " + "11:00:00" + " " + "PM";

        if (dateTimePicker1.Value != dateTimePicker2.Value)
        {
            string ConnString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\Data\Test.accdb";
            DataTable Data = new DataTable();
            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnString))
            {
                conn.Open();//break

                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select tb3.SeqNo as 'Session Sequence Number',tb3.SessionDate as 'Session Date',tb3.CustomerName as 'Customer Name',tb3.RepID as 'Rep ID',tb3.RepName as 'Rep Name',CaseRef as 'Ticket No',PracticeName as 'Practice Name',PostCode as 'Post Code',PhoneManner as 'Phone Manner',Satisfaction,iif (Satisfaction='EXCELLENT',5, iif (Satisfaction='VERY GOOD' ,4, iif (Satisfaction='GOOD' ,3, iif (Satisfaction='NEUTRAL' ,2, iif (Satisfaction='POOR' ,1))))) as Ratings,Ratings/5*100 as 'Percentage' , Consultant,CustomerComments as 'Customer Comments',Recommendation from tb1,tb3 where tb3.SeqNo=tb1.SeqNo and tb3.SessionDate between #" + fromdate + "# and #" + todate + "#", conn);
                OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                adapter.Fill(Data);
                conn.Close();
                dataGridView1.DataSource = Data;

                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application objexcelapp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                objexcelapp.Application.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
                objexcelapp.Columns.ColumnWidth = 25;
                for (int i = 1; i < gridviewID.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
                {
                    objexcelapp.Cells[1, i] = gridviewID.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
                }
                /*For storing Each row and column value to excel sheet*/
                for (int i = 0; i < gridviewID.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < gridviewID.Columns.Count; j++)
                    {
                        if (gridviewID.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value != null)
                        {
                            objexcelapp.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = gridviewID.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
                MessageBox.Show("Your excel file exported successfully at d:\\" + excelFilename + ".xlsx");
                objexcelapp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs("d:\\" + excelFilename + ".xlsx");
                objexcelapp.ActiveWorkbook.Saved = true;
            }
        }
        else

        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select valid date...!!!");
        }
    }

}
}
```

Hello,

I am trying to export the data from the ACCDB file to Excel.

and its working but when I am export in excel file is empty there is no data.

Comment: Don't use Interop. It will only cause trouble. Use a specialized library like [EPPlus](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/epplus/drafts/98280).

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please chose a proper title for your question. A dumped function signature is not a good title. Also please take care to use proper tags. Your code is not related to C language but C++ or C#.